# Running Azcopy in parallel - bottleneck?

Tags: azure, azure-devtest-labs

I want to download/upload files to Azure in parallel. 
AzCopy, by default does not allow multiple runs on the same copy because of the locks on journal files. I am running multiple Azcopy instances on the same machine by pointing each of these instances to different journal files (using /Z )

But what is the bottle-neck in doing this? Bandwidth is obvious, but what is the bottleneck from Azure's side.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real bottleneck from Azure's sides. Keep in mind though that the transfers are done with spare bandwidth and that there is no SLA as to whether it'll be fast or slow. That's all.

The other bottleneck you may need to check is your local CPU, when running over 4 AzCopy instances in parallel with 4 parallel uploads each my i7 starts to sweat a bit.